# Strange reading from rectifier

Tags: rectifier

I am new here so sorry if i don't ask this question correctly.

I am currently trying to test a bridge rectifier from jameco(part # 103000)

I am applying a 60hZ wave from wave generator with 1V peak to peak.

I am getting a fluctuating DC voltage of 530-650mv and when no AC input is connecting to the rectifier, I am still getting 300mV on the DC output. Can anyone explain this?

Please let me know if you need more clarification/explanation.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Try lightly loading the rectified output with something like a 1 kohm resistor. Also, I think you might need a bigger AC signal. Normal bridge rectifier will barely produce any dc output until the ac input is above 1 volt p-p.

Comment: If it is a normal silicon diode bridge rectifier - as evidenced by the Jameco description - "Diode Rectifier Bridge Single 100 Volt 1A 4-Pin DFM" there would be little or no output till the input was more like 1.2 or 1.3 volt p-p. The Diodes Inc DF005M data sheet confirms this showing each individual diode with a > 0.6V forward threshold.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Readings are making much more sense now!